# Inner product within an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, inner-products

I have

$$\langle v-2\langle u,v\rangle u,w-2\langle u,w\rangle u\rangle$$

I tried using linearity, but I got this mess

$$\langle v,w\rangle -\langle v,2\langle u,w\rangle u\rangle -\langle 2\langle u,v\rangle u,w\rangle +\langle 2\langle u,v\rangle u,2\langle u,w\rangle u\rangle$$

I know it all cancels to $\langle v,w\rangle$ but I can't see how?

Comment: Before the last term, there should be no minus.

Comment: Hint: the inner product is a scalar and so can be pulled out of the other inner products

Comment: `<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for that meaning only; to make angle brackets, use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thank you, corrected it.

Comment: Are you assuming $\langle u, u \rangle =1$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I'm not sure, this is from a question. $u$ is a fixed unit vector.

Comment: Unit vector means $\Vert u \Vert=1$. Thus $\langle u, u \rangle= \Vert u \Vert^2 = 1.$

Comment: @nyquist_plot Why not making your comment an answer? I think this would be perfectly fine. I think a question should not be answered in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ended up with
$$\langle v,w\rangle -\langle v,2\langle u,w\rangle u\rangle -\langle 2\langle u,v\rangle u,w\rangle +\langle 2\langle u,v\rangle u,2\langle u,w\rangle u\rangle$$
Now use the fact you can "pull constants out of the inner product":
$$\langle v,w\rangle -2\langle u,w\rangle \langle v,u\rangle -2\langle u,v\rangle\langle  u,w\rangle +4\langle u,v\rangle\langle u,w\rangle\langle  u, u\rangle$$
Using the symmetry $\langle u,v\rangle = \langle v, u \rangle$ and the fact $u$ is a unit vector ($\langle u,u \rangle = 1$), you end up with 
$$\langle v,w\rangle -2\langle u,w\rangle \langle u,v\rangle -2\langle u,v\rangle\langle  u,w\rangle +4\langle u,v\rangle\langle u,w\rangle = \langle v,w \rangle$$

Comment: Why is the symmetry not a conjugate? And when you pull the constant out in the second term, why is this also not a conjugate?